# TypeError:Cannot read propreties of undefined (reading storage)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload a product information into firebase with an image with flutter (mobile app) But i get an error "TypeError:Cannot read propreties of undefined (reading storage)
here is my function to upload into firebase :

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
void _uploadForm() async{
    if(_titleController.text==""|| _priceController.text==""||_quantiteController.text==""||_codeController.text==""||_pickedImage == null){
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("Vous devez remplir les champs!"),
    backgroundColor:Colors.red,));}
          final _uuid = const Uuid().v4();

    try{
      setState(() {
          loading = true;
        });
        fb.StorageReference storageRef =
            fb.storage().ref().child('productsImages').child(_uuid + 'jpg');
        final fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot =
            await storageRef.put(kIsWeb ? webImage :_pickedImage).future;
        Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').doc(_uuid).set({
          'id': _uuid,
          'title': _titleController.text,
          'price': _priceController.text,
          'CodeBar': _codeController.text,
          'imageUrl': imageUri.toString(),
          'Quantité': _quantiteController.text,
          'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
        });
        _clearForm();
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Product uploaded succefully",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          // backgroundColor: ,
          // textColor: ,
          // fontSize: 16.0
        );

    }on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        GlobalMethods.errorDialog(
            subtitle: '${error.message}', context: context);
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        GlobalMethods.errorDialog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the [`package:firebase/firebase.dart`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase), which only exposes the Realtime Database and Firestore products of Firebase. It does not expose Cloud Storage, which you're trying to use. Also, at the top of the [package page](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) on pub.dev it says:

> This package is discontinued and will receive no further updates.

And:

> If you're looking for a package to use in your Flutter app, please have a look at the official documentation: firebase.google.com/docs/flutter.

I'd indeed to the latter, which will then lead to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/start) for using Cloud Storage.